# Searching for mature fictional story about a scientist who uses a car crash victim to build an AI

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

The story involves a scientist that has hit a roadblock. He then witnesses a car accident and he then takes the victim of said accident and uses her as the base for his AI program.
The story follows the progress of the AI as it gains more sentience.
The story also contains mentioning of latex.

No idea what the title was or where I read it before.
Anyone know which story I read?

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Have you taken the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)? It might help if you could provide more information, like the approximate period in time when you read this, and/or in what language.

Comment: Is that "latex" as in rubber, or "LaTeX" as in typesetting?

Comment: latex as the material and the story was in english, halve a year ago was when i read it

Comment: Did this story have a horror-oriented vibe (it sounds pretty unsettling)? Or was finding the car crash victim more incidental in the story?

Comment: The accident was slightly unsettling described, i think he put the woman in a freezer, weird way to react for the person. I think the it was described as a hit and flee car crash. It's slightly creepy in the end, when the A.I. starts to go fully self aware.